# When two people join my Twilio Video room, only one participant receives audio and video?

Tags: javascript, php, twilio, twilio-php

Every time participant 2 shows up, their audio and camera recording shows up on participant 1's screen. But participant 1's audio/video doesn't show up on participant 2's screen. So whoever is the first person to join their video and audio isn't transmitted to the other participants?

```
<h1>Hi there!</h1>
<div class="videos">
  <div id="video-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="remote-media-div">
</div>



<?php
include('./vendor/autoload.php');
include('./config.php');

use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;

// Use identity and room from query string if provided

$identity = isset($_GET["identity"]) ? $_GET["identity"] : "identity" . rand();
$room = isset($_GET["room"]) ? $_GET["room"] :  "testingreal";

// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
$token = new AccessToken(
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    $TWILIO_API_KEY,
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET,
    3600,
    $identity
);

// Grant access to Video
$grant = new VideoGrant();
$grant->setRoom($room);
$token->addGrant($grant);

echo $token->toJWT();

?>



<script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.3/twilio-video.min.js"></script>

<script>

var Video = Twilio.Video;
console.log(Video);


var connect = Video.connect;

Video.connect('<?=$token->toJWT()?>', { name: 'testingreal' }).then(room => {
  console.log('Conmnected to Room "%s"', room.name);

    room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
    console.log(`Participant "${participant.identity}" connected`);
    console.log('testing 213');

    participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {

        if (publication.isSubscribed) {
        const track = publication.track;
        document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
        }
    });

    participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => {
        document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
    });
    });  


});
```

The logging I inserted in the room.on('participantConnected', participant => { //code } doesn't show up when I first join the room as participant 1. But I notice once participant 2 shows up the logging does appear. So I am wondering how I set the room.on('participantConnected') code to execute right when the first participant joins, and not the 2nd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twillio video is just based on peer to peer connection.
To be more than 2~4+ users in a room it should be based on SFU and MCU methodology.

Here is the link for more details.

- [ https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/scalability-in-video-conferencing-part-1-276f52b4acac ]

p2p connection is always working well with 1:1 connection but as you can read in the above article it should be based on SFU or MCU to be more than 3+ participants.
Actually hangout and zoom are also based on MCU.