# Mobile web Video Chat screen layout?

Tags: reactjs, video, flexbox

I am building a React website with a 1-to-1 video chat feature. Basically recreating Facetime but instead of a native app it will be through a website.

Everything is up and running I am just trying to dial in the UI.

I want the user to see a small local copy of their video (like on Facetime) in the bottom left corner. And I want them to see their friend's video over all/most of the screen.

The thing is people may chat from mobile devices, or computers. The aspect ratio or width/height of the video feed changes depending on what device a user is using and what orientation that device is in. Because of this I need to dynamically handle showing both video stream (the local, and partner's video) in the correct dimensions.

I suppose one option is to specify the dimensions of the parent div that holds the video streams for each screen size using the @media queries. However this seems verbose and prone to breaking when a new screen size comes out.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue and have suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I guess you are using p2p webrtc technology for building 1:1 video chat.
We don't usually use p2p due to it's limited performance.

[When two people join my Twilio Video room, only one participant receives audio and video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567404/when-two-people-join-my-twilio-video-room-only-one-participant-receives-audio-a/64567468#64567468)

As you can see here, we really have performance issues with p2p connection.
Due to the reason, I think you need to reduce the screen resolution for p2p connection as much as possible and then on client's side you need to put the width and height of video player larger than screen resolution for p2p connection.

For instance,

When you try to make a p2p connection, you can specify the resolution like this :

```
let mediaConstraints = {
    video: {
      width: {max: 640},
      height: {max: 480},
      frameRate: {max: 30},
    },
    audio: true
};
```

But on client's side, I mean in HTML, you can specify the width & height of the video player higher than the resolution like this :

`<video style="width: 1024px; height: 840px" />`